# ARKit - How to download 3d model from server URL?

Tags: ios, swift, arkit

I'm trying to download 3d model from URl and place into ARKit app. This is my code:

```
func addItem(hitTestResult: ARHitTestResult) {
    let url = URL(string: "https://doc-0k-9s-docs.googleusercontent.com/docs/securesc/hbcaqfp5mt16eq0ub4t5v9ch588idcc9/66jirrfaadh438gudijui5vq39hblj21/1519236000000/11854387276548053415/11854387276548053415/1ab55L4__Qy7HSPf10-a4H3lqUdWSvPLl?e=download")
    if let objectScene = try? SCNScene(url: url!, options: [.overrideAssetURLs: true]) {
        print("load successful")
        let node = SCNNode()
        for childNode in objectScene.rootNode.childNodes {
            node.addChildNode(childNode)
        }
        sceneView.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(node)
    } else {
        print("Error loading")
    }
}
```

It's crash at objectScene line. How to resolve this issues. Thank you